# How to set git-gutter's default encoding

Tags: git, character-encoding

Every time I visit a buffer containing characters such as 'ç' 'á' 'ã' or 'é', emacs throws out this error:

```
These default coding systems were tried to encode text
in the buffer ‘ *temp file*’:
  (utf-8-unix (1444 . 4194275) (1476 . 4194275))
However, each of them encountered characters it couldn’t encode:
  utf-8-unix cannot encode these:  \343 \343

Click on a character (or switch to this window by ‘M-m w w’
and select the characters by RET) to jump to the place it appears,
where ‘M-m u C-x =’ will give information about it.

Select one of the safe coding systems listed below,
or cancel the writing with C-g and edit the buffer
   to remove or modify the problematic characters,
or specify any other coding system (and risk losing
   the problematic characters).

  raw-text no-conversion
```

I know it's `git-gutter`'s fault, because if I set `debug-on-entry` to trip on `select-safe-coding-system` it spits out:

```
Debugger entered--entering a function:
* select-safe-coding-system(1 5131 utf-8-unix nil "/tmp/git-gutter-origyPvhXw")
  write-region(nil nil "/tmp/git-gutter-origyPvhXw" nil 0)
  git-gutter:write-original-content("/tmp/git-gutter-origyPvhXw" "/path/to/file/im/at")
  git-gutter:live-update()
  apply(git-gutter:live-update nil)
  timer-event-handler([t 0 2 0 t git-gutter:live-update nil idle 0])
```

but I've already set utf-8 as default with

```lisp
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-language-environment 'utf-8)
```

Investigating further, this only seems to happen after I (accidentally) tried to open .xlsx with emacs (and trying to open it causes more encoding errors immediately) in the same file tree as the source files.

Files on the same repository but above it or not 'under it' seem unaffected.

Copying the same 'problematic' characters to another source controlled file seems fine.

#### Info

Emacs version: Spacemacs rolling release @ emacs 27.1

###### How can I set the default encoding for git-gutter/solve this without disabling `git-gutter`?

p.s.: this is a continuation of [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70282/how-to-remove-characters-causing-encoding-error).

Comment: using some utf-8 sample files, i've got no issues w/ my daily-driver emacs (which includes `git-gutter`. maybe you could add or post someplace (a gist?) of the failing text.

Comment: it seems it's not just the failing characters fault, in this case it was 'ç' and 'ó', but copy pasting them somewhere (git controlled) else seems fine.

Comment: @nega: what if your sample files are in `iso-8859-1` with 'ç' and 'ó' included? Stab in the dark BTW - I have no idea what's happening :-)

Comment: That did work, because I don't see any encoding errors if I set the default coding system to `iso-8859-1`. Bullseye! which variables do I need to change with a `.dir-locals.el` for this to be more of a permanent solution?